# is redis pub/sub realistic in php?

Tags: php, redis, publish-subscribe, messagebroker, paas

I'd like to use redis pub/sub in PHP, but I'm afraid PHP can't be the only tool: a subscriber need to be always callable, since php isn't built for running as a daemon, I can't trust it to reliably be always "on".

So what is the solution for the PHP world?

1. don't use pub/sub, use other redis' storages with a crontask launching php every x minutes
2. use a broker which will call php?
3. other?

With the "2." I mean : use a **nodejs**/java/fooBar server which is the daemonized subscriber and call back the php (using http/cli or whatever).

I can't find a better idea than the "2." , but it seem so ineffective at the same way...

What is your opinion?

---

**EDIT** :
How would you do this using a cloud platform like platform.sh which do not give the opportunity to have a supervisor.d alike?

Comment: Just run php daemons work fine for me. Laravel has support for redis pub/sub

Comment: I don't know php tech, but I think there _were_ something for daemonizing php code.

Comment: @MikeMiller does it work well? Is it long term stable or do you have to make workaround like relaunching the daemon every X time? 
I'm concerned it would end has using the bad tool for the task : PHP is built as a short life script language, I know it had memleaks with cross referenced array for example.

Comment: https://redis.io/clients#php could give some ideas...

Comment: I found this project : https://github.com/michelsalib/BCCResqueBundle wich can work in conjunction with http://supervisord.org/ in order to have background workers.

From now I started to code a more humble code wich will rely on the cron tab I'll see if I feel the need of a more robust solution (wich seem also so far much more complex)

Comment: @bruno you need to run it with supervisor.d or similar to keep it up if the script errors. You should probably look at some php CLI library like http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html. I have stable projects been around for a couple of years and had no issues

Comment: @MikeMiller I've installed supervisor.d, it's surprisingly simple to configure. I just have a question : I created my php CLI script to end after 60 seconds (I had in mind to relaunch it every minutes with a cron job).
Will supervisor.d relaunch my program each time it end by itself (without an error), or do I have to git it an infinite duration?

Comment: @bruno you could do. Before switching to the symfony component I ran them in infinite loops with a second sleep so it didn't go too crazy. Not sure what symfony is up to but I reckon it's the same thing. Only thing to remember of you go that way is you need to restart after a code change or it will keep running your old code

Comment: I have a new question : how would you handle this if you use platform.sh alike, wich seem to not permit a superviror.d alike?
PS : do you think that I should ask a new question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I found a satisfying way to go : use of supervisor.d which will relaunch a symfony Command script with :

- `set_time_limit(0)`
- an infinite loop
- a blocking call to redis (a `BRPOP` with a max way of 1 sec. lower than the read_write_timeout)

  - it is important to do a blocking command, in order to not consume all the CPU time
  - I would event go to a real pub/sub, but for now, I only have one listener so it don't matter

what I can tell from an early point of view :

- supervisor.d is really easy to install/configure, the doc is complete, I didn't run in any problem, it's very rare + satisfying!
- it seems to works well
- logs are written, so it may be more easy to understand futur crashes
- in case of X successive and near crashes, the service is stopped, I didn't find a way to be notified of this, it is really a problem, I think I'll go to [this solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/241721/get-notification-from-supervisord-when-a-job-exits)([doc](http://superlance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crashmail.html))
- like @Mike Miller said : "*Only thing to remember of you go that way is you need to restart after a code change or it will keep running your old code*"